# Python2 like behaviour in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, jupyter-notebook

I am running a Jupyter Notebook, running Python3 on a Macbook (OS X Sierra). The only recent change I have made is to install Jupyter Notebook Extensions. Now I get Python 2.x like division instead of the expected behaviour from Python 3.x, which should return a float.

[image: Screenshot of Python3 Division on Jupyter Notebooks]

This doesn't seem to be a problem when I type in the same commands in terminal.

[image]

What explains this behaviour, and what can I do to get back the original Python 3.x division?

Comment: It sure looks like you actually have a Python 2 notebook (despite the Python 3 in the top right corner of your image). What does `import sys; print(sys.version)` show you?

Answer (score 0):

I would try some of the options in the DOC: 
http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html

You can **import**:

```
from __future__ import division
```

So Python 2 and 3 are in "compatibility mode". You need to install:

```
pip install future
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks - but I haven't used Python 2 for months now. I only have it incase I need to run any old code. And in Jupyter, it is running the Python 3 kernel already.

Comment: Could you print your Jupyter Notebook Extension version? Also your IPython version? It seems to be some diferences between releases:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython